# pointer targets in passing argument 3 of 'unpack_code' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign], how to solve this?

Tags: c

I have a long program, when I try to run it, it doesn't compile and return 255 occur, two warning always appear:

```
warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of 'unpack_code' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]

In file included from read_chn.c:3:0:
read_chn.h:104:5: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'unsigned int *'
```

after searching i found that **p_ch_beg parameter may cause the problem (if i'm right)but i don't know what to do. please help to correct the script bellow

```
int unpack_code(unsigned int **p_ch_beg , int *p_ch_bit, int *p_code, int numbits, int wsize, unsigned int erasemaks)  {
            int ret_code;
            int i,ch_bit;
            unsigned int *ch_word;
        
            ch_bit = *p_ch_bit;
            ch_word = *p_ch_beg;
            *p_code = 0;
                ret_code = *ch_word & ERASE_MASK;
        
            for (i = 0; i < numbits; i++) {
                /* Mask in bit from channel word to code    */
                *p_code |= (((*ch_word & (1<<ch_bit)) >> ch_bit) << i);
        
                /* Check for end of channel word        */
                if (++ch_bit >= wsize) {
                    ch_bit = 0;
                    (*p_ch_beg)++ ;
                    ch_word++ ;
                }
            }
        
            /*  Save updated bit counter    */
            *p_ch_bit = ch_bit;
        
        
            /* Catch erasure in new word if read */
            if (ch_bit != 0)
              ret_code |= *ch_word & ERASE_MASK;
        
            return(ret_code);
        }

        /*  i will use it like this:  */
        
         for (i = 0; i < NUM_CH_BITS; i++)
         {
        erase |= unpack_code(&par-> chptr, &par> chbit,&bit_buffer[bit_order[i]] ,1, CHWORDSIZE,ERASE_MASK);
            bit_ptr++;
            }
```

I'll poste the huge programe for more details:

```
   // main program
   
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include"read_chn.h"
   
   
   
   struct s
   {
       float pitch;
       float lsf[LPC_ORD+1];
       float gain[NUM_GAINFR];
       float jitter;
       float bpvc[NUM_BANDS];
       int pitch_index;
       int lsf_index[LPC_ORD];
       int jit_index;
       int bpvc_index;
       int gain_index[NUM_GAINFR];
       unsigned int *chptr;
       int chbit;
       int uv_flag;
       float fs_mag[NUM_HARM];
       int *fsvq_index;
       int *msvq_index;
       int msvq_stages;
       int *msvq_bits;
       int *msvq_levels;
   };
   int main(){
       struct s a[400],b[400];
       FILE *fptr;
       int i,j,eras;
       int num_frames = 0;
       fptr=fopen("data.bit","rb");
   
   
       fseek(fptr,0L,2);
       length = ftell(fptr);
       rewind(fptr);
       num_frames = 0.5 + length * (8.0 / NUM_CH_BITS) * (6.0/32);
   
         melp_par.chbit = 0;
         fread(b,(int)sizeof(b),1,fptr);
         melp_par.chptr = chbuf;
         eras =melp_chn_read(&melp_par,&prev_par);
   
       for(i=0;i<5;++i)
       {
   
   for(j=0;j<=10;j++){
       printf("      lsf[%d]=%f\n",i,b[i].lsf[j]);
   
   }
   for(j=0;j<=10;j++){
       printf("   fs_mag[%d]=%f\n",i, b[i].fs_mag[j]);
   
   }
   for(j=0;j<=10;j++){
   
       printf("lsf_index[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i].lsf_index[j]);
   }
   
   for (j=0;j<2;j++){
      printf("gain[%d]=%f\n",i,b[i].gain[j]);
   
   }
   
   for (j=0;j<5;j++){
      printf("bpvc[%d]=%f\n",i,b[i].bpvc[j]);
   }
   for (j=0;j<5;j++){
      printf("gain_index[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i].gain_index[j]);
   }
   printf("       pitch[%d]=%f\n",i,b[i].pitch);
   printf("      jitter[%d]=%f\n",i,b[i].jitter);
   printf("       pitch[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i].pitch_index);
   printf("jitter_index[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i].jit_index);
   printf("  bpvc_index[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i].bpvc_index);
   printf("       chptr[%d]=%d\n",i,*b[i].chptr);
   printf("       chbit[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i].chbit);
   printf("     uv_flag[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i].uv_flag);
   printf("  fsvq_index[%d]=%d\n",i,*b[i].fsvq_index);
   printf("  msvq_index[%d]=%d\n",i,*b[i].msvq_index);
   printf(" msvq_stages[%d]=%d\n",i,b[i].msvq_stages);
   
   printf("msvq_bits[%d]=%d\n",i,*b[i].msvq_bits);
   
   printf("msvq_levels[%d]=%d\n",i,*b[i].msvq_levels);
       }
       fclose(fptr);
   
   return 0;
   }
   
   // channel read program
   
   
   
   #include"read_chn.h"
   #include<stddef.h>
   #include<math.h>
   #include"spbstd.h"
   
   int pmat74[3][4] = {{1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,1},{0,1,1,1}};
   int pmat84[4][4] = {{1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,1},{0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0}};
   int syntab74[8] = {BEP_CORR,6,5,2,4,1,0,3};
   
     int syntab84[16] =
   {
       BEP_CORR,    /* 0x0 */
       7,           /* 0x1 */
       6,           /* 0x2 */
       BEP_UNCORR,  /* 0x3 */
       5,           /* 0x4 */
       BEP_UNCORR,  /* 0x5 */
       BEP_UNCORR,  /* 0x6 */
       2,           /* 0x7 */
       4,           /* 0x8 */
       BEP_UNCORR,  /* 0x9 */
       BEP_UNCORR,  /* 0xA */
       1,           /* 0xB */
       BEP_UNCORR,  /* 0xC */
       0,           /* 0xD */
       3,           /* 0xE */
       BEP_UNCORR   /* 0xF */
   };
    int pitch_dec[1<<PIT_BITS] =
   {
   UV_PIND, /* 0x0 */
   UV_PIND, /* 0x1 */
   UV_PIND, /* 0x2 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x3 */
   UV_PIND, /* 0x4 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x5 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x6 */
   2, /* 0x7 */
   UV_PIND, /* 0x8 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x9 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0xA */
   3, /* 0xB */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0xC */
   4, /* 0xD */
   5, /* 0xE */
   6, /* 0xF */
   UV_PIND, /* 0x10 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x11 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x12 */
   7, /* 0x13 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x14 */
   8, /* 0x15 */
   9, /* 0x16 */
   10, /* 0x17 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x18 */
   11, /* 0x19 */
   12, /* 0x1A */
   13, /* 0x1B */
   14, /* 0x1C */
   15, /* 0x1D */
   16, /* 0x1E */
   17, /* 0x1F */
   UV_PIND, /* 0x20 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x21 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x22 */
   18, /* 0x23 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x24 */
   19, /* 0x25 */
   20, /* 0x26 */
   21, /* 0x27 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x28 */
   22, /* 0x29 */
   23, /* 0x2A */
   24, /* 0x2B */
   25, /* 0x2C */
   26, /* 0x2D */
   27, /* 0x2E */
   28, /* 0x2F */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x30 */
   29, /* 0x31 */
   30, /* 0x32 */
   31, /* 0x33 */
   32, /* 0x34 */
   33, /* 0x35 */
   34, /* 0x36 */
   35, /* 0x37 */
   36, /* 0x38 */
   37, /* 0x39 */
   38, /* 0x3A */
   39, /* 0x3B */
   40, /* 0x3C */
   41, /* 0x3D */
   42, /* 0x3E */
   43, /* 0x3F */
   UV_PIND, /* 0x40 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x41 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x42 */
   44, /* 0x43 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x44 */
   45, /* 0x45 */
   46, /* 0x46 */
   47, /* 0x47 */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x48 */
   48, /* 0x49 */
   49, /* 0x4A */
   50, /* 0x4B */
   51, /* 0x4C */
   52, /* 0x4D */
   53, /* 0x4E */
   54, /* 0x4F */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x50 */
   55, /* 0x51 */
   56, /* 0x52 */
   57, /* 0x53 */
   58, /* 0x54 */
   59, /* 0x55 */
   60, /* 0x56 */
   61, /* 0x57 */
   62, /* 0x58 */
   63, /* 0x59 */
   64, /* 0x5A */
   65, /* 0x5B */
   66, /* 0x5C */
   67, /* 0x5D */
   68, /* 0x5E */
   69, /* 0x5F */
   INVAL_PIND, /* 0x60 */
   70, /* 0x61 */
   71, /* 0x62 */
   72, /* 0x63 */
   73, /* 0x64 */
   74, /* 0x65 */
   75, /* 0x66 */
   76, /* 0x67 */
   77, /* 0x68 */
   78, /* 0x69 */
   79, /* 0x6A */
   80, /* 0x6B */
   81, /* 0x6C */
   82, /* 0x6D */
   83, /* 0x6E */
   84, /* 0x6F */
   85, /* 0x70 */
   86, /* 0x71 */
   87, /* 0x72 */
   88, /* 0x73 */
   89, /* 0x74 */
   90, /* 0x75 */
   91, /* 0x76 */
   92, /* 0x77 */
   93, /* 0x78 */
   94, /* 0x79 */
   95, /* 0x7A */
   96, /* 0x7B */
   97, /* 0x7C */
   98, /* 0x7D */
   99, /* 0x7E */
   100 /* 0x7F */
   };
   
   
   int melp_chn_read(struct melp_param *par, struct melp_param *prev_par)
   {
   
       int erase = 0;
       int i, bit_cntr;
       unsigned int *bit_ptr;
       static int bit_buffer[NUM_CH_BITS];
       /*  Read channel output buffer into bit buffer */
       bit_ptr = bit_buffer;
       for (i = 0; i < NUM_CH_BITS; i++) {
       erase |= unpack_code(&par->chptr,&par->chbit,&bit_buffer[bit_order[i]],1,CHWORDSIZE,ERASE_MASK);
       bit_ptr++;
       }
   
       /*  Read information from  bit buffer   */
       bit_ptr = bit_buffer;
       bit_cntr = 0;
   
       unpack_code(&bit_ptr,&bit_cntr,&par->gain_index[1],5,1,0);
   
       /* Read sync bit */
       unpack_code(&bit_ptr,&bit_cntr,&i,1,1,0);
       unpack_code(&bit_ptr,&bit_cntr,&par->gain_index[0],3,1,0);
       unpack_code(&bit_ptr,&bit_cntr,&par->pitch_index,PIT_BITS,1,0);
   
       unpack_code(&bit_ptr,&bit_cntr,&par->jit_index,1,1,0);
       unpack_code(&bit_ptr,&bit_cntr,&par->bpvc_index,
                NUM_BANDS-1,1,0);
   
       for (i = 0; i < par->msvq_stages; i++)
         unpack_code(&bit_ptr,&bit_cntr,&par->msvq_index[i],
                  par->msvq_bits[i],1,0);
   
       unpack_code(&bit_ptr,&bit_cntr,&par->fsvq_index[0],
                FS_BITS,1,0);
   
       /* Clear unvoiced flag */
       par->uv_flag = 0;
   
       erase = fec_decode(par,erase);
   
       /* Decode new frame if no erasures occurred */
       if (erase) {
   
       /* Erasure: frame repeat */
   
       /* Save correct values of pointers */
       prev_par->chptr = par->chptr;
       prev_par->chbit = par->chbit;
       *par = *prev_par;
   
       /* Force all subframes to equal last one */
       for (i = 0; i < NUM_GAINFR-1; i++) {
           par->gain[i] = par->gain[NUM_GAINFR-1];
       }
       }
       else {
   
       /* Decode line spectrum frequencies */
       vq_msd2(msvq_cb,&par->lsf[1],(float*)NULL,(float*)NULL,par->msvq_index,
           par->msvq_levels,par->msvq_stages,LPC_ORD,0);
       i = FS_LEVELS;
       if (par->uv_flag)
         fill(par->fs_mag,1.,NUM_HARM);
       else
         {
             /* Decode Fourier magnitudes */
             vq_msd2(fsvq_cb,par->fs_mag,(float*)NULL,(float*)NULL,
                 par->fsvq_index,&i,1,NUM_HARM,0);
         }
   
       /* Decode gain terms with uniform log quantizer */
       q_gain_dec(par->gain, par->gain_index,GN_QLO,GN_QUP,GN_QLEV);
   
       /* Fractional pitch: */
       /* Decode logarithmic pitch period */
       if (par->uv_flag)
         par->pitch = UV_PITCH;
       else
         {
             quant_u_dec(par->pitch_index,&par->pitch,PIT_QLO,PIT_QUP,PIT_QLEV);
             par->pitch = pow(10.0,par->pitch);
         }
   
       /* Decode jitter and bandpass voicing */
       quant_u_dec(par->jit_index,&par->jitter,0.0,MAX_JITTER,2);
       q_bpvc_dec(&par->bpvc[0],&par->bpvc_index,par->uv_flag,
              NUM_BANDS);
       }
   
       /* Return erase flag */
       return(erase);
   }
   
   /*                              */
   /*  Subroutine UNPACK_CODE: Unpack bit code from channel.   */
   /*      Return 1 if erasure, otherwise 0.                       */
   /*
   */
   int unpack_code( unsigned int (**p_ch_beg), int *p_ch_bit, int *p_code, int numbits, int wsize,unsigned int erasemaks)
   
   {
   
       int ret_code;
       int i,ch_bit;
       unsigned int *ch_word;
   
       ch_bit = *p_ch_bit;
       ch_word = *p_ch_beg;
       *p_code = 0;
           ret_code = *ch_word & ERASE_MASK;
   
       for (i = 0; i < numbits; i++) {
           /* Mask in bit from channel word to code    */
           *p_code |= (((*ch_word & (1<<ch_bit)) >> ch_bit) << i);
   
           /* Check for end of channel word        */
           if (++ch_bit >= wsize) {
               ch_bit = 0;
               (**p_ch_beg)++ ;
               ch_word++ ;
           }
       }
   
       /*  Save updated bit counter    */
       *p_ch_bit = ch_bit;
   
   
       /* Catch erasure in new word if read */
       if (ch_bit != 0)
         ret_code |= *ch_word & ERASE_MASK;
   
       return(ret_code);
   }
   
   void fill(float output[], float fillval, int npts)
   {
     int i;
   
     for (i = 0; i < npts; i++ )
       output[i] = fillval;
   
   }
   
   #define GAIN_INT_DB 5.0
   
   void q_gain_dec(float *gain,int *gain_index,float GNQLO,float GNQUP,float GNQLEV)
   {
   
       static float prev_gain = 0.0;
       static int prev_gain_err = 0;
       float temp,temp2;
   
       /* Decode second gain term */
       quant_u_dec(gain_index[1],&gain[1],GN_QLO,GN_QUP,GN_QLEV);
   
       if (gain_index[0] == 0) {
   
       /* interpolation bit code for intermediate gain */
       if (fabs(gain[1] - prev_gain) > GAIN_INT_DB) {
           /* Invalid received data (bit error) */
           if (prev_gain_err == 0) {
           /* First time: don't allow gain excursion */
           gain[1] = prev_gain;
           }
           prev_gain_err = 1;
       }
       else
         prev_gain_err = 0;
   
       /* Use interpolated gain value */
       gain[0] = 0.5*(gain[1]+prev_gain);
       }
   
       else {
   
       /* Decode 7-bit quantizer for first gain term */
       prev_gain_err = 0;
       gain_index[0]--;
       if (prev_gain < gain[1]) {
           temp = prev_gain;
           temp2 = gain[1];
       }
       else {
           temp = gain[1];
           temp2 = prev_gain;
       }
       temp -= 6.0;
       temp2 += 6.0;
       if (temp < GN_QLO)
         temp = GN_QLO;
       if (temp2 > GN_QUP)
         temp2 = GN_QUP;
       quant_u_dec(gain_index[0],&gain[0],temp,temp2,7);
       }
   
       /* Update previous gain for next time */
       prev_gain = gain[1];
   
   }
   void quant_u_dec(int index, float *p_data,float qmin, float qmax, int nlev)
   
   {
   register float  step;
   
       /*  Define symmetrical quantizer stepsize   */
       step = (qmax - qmin) / (nlev - 1);
   
       /*  Decode quantized level          */
       *p_data = qmin + (index * step);
   
   }
   
   #define INVALID_BPVC 0001
   
   void q_bpvc_dec(float *bpvc,int *bpvc_index,int uv_flag,int NUMBANDS)
   
   {
       int j;
   
       if (uv_flag) {
   
       /* Unvoiced: set all bpvc to 0 */
       *bpvc_index = 0;
       bpvc[0] = 0.0;
       }
   
       else {
   
       /* Voiced: set bpvc[0] to 1.0 */
       bpvc[0] = 1.0;
       }
   
       if (*bpvc_index == INVALID_BPVC) {
   
       /* Invalid code received: set higher band voicing to zero */
       *bpvc_index = 0;
       }
   
       /* Decode remaining bands */
       for (j = NUM_BANDS-1; j > 0; j--) {
       if ((*bpvc_index & 1) == 1)
           bpvc[j] = 1.0;
       else
           bpvc[j] = 0.0;
       *bpvc_index >>= 1;
       }
   }
   
   int fec_decode(struct melp_param *par,int erase)
   
   {
   
       int pitch_dec[1<<PIT_BITS]; /* Pitch index decoding table */
       int berr_pos;
   
       /* Decode pitch index */
       par->pitch_index = pitch_dec[par->pitch_index];
   
   /*
   ** Set unvoiced flag for pitch index of UV_PIND; set erase flag for invalid
   ** pitch index INVAL_PIND.  Otherwise, convert pitch index into quantization
   ** level.
   */
       if (!(par->uv_flag = par->pitch_index == UV_PIND) &&
       !(erase |= par->pitch_index == INVAL_PIND))
       par->pitch_index-=2; /* Subtract to acct. for reserved pitch codes.*/
   
       if (par->uv_flag && !erase)
   /*
   ** Unvoiced case - use spare parameter bits for error control coding.
   */
       {
   /*
   ** Decode 4 MSB of first vq stage index using (8,4) Hamming code; parity bits
   ** in bpvc index.  Set bpvc index to zero.
   */
       vgetbits(codewd84,par->msvq_index[0],6,4);
       vgetbits(&codewd84[4],par->bpvc_index,3,4);
       berr_pos=sbc_dec(codewd84,8,4,&pmat84[0][0],syntab84);
       erase |= berr_pos == BEP_UNCORR;
       par->msvq_index[0]=vsetbits(par->msvq_index[0],6,4,codewd84);
       par->bpvc_index = 0;
   
       /* Perform remaining decoding only if no frame repeat flagged. */
       if (!erase)
       {
   /*
   ** Decode 3 LSB of first vq stage index using (7,4) Hamming code; parity bits
   ** in 3 MSB of fsvq index.
   */
           vgetbits(codewd74,par->msvq_index[0],2,3);
           codewd74[3] = 0;
           vgetbits(&codewd74[4],par->fsvq_index[0],7,3);
           berr_pos=sbc_dec(codewd74,7,4,&pmat74[0][0],syntab74);
           par->msvq_index[0]=vsetbits(par->msvq_index[0],2,3,codewd74);
   /*
   ** Decode 4 MSB of second gain index using (7,4) Hamming code; parity bits in
   ** next 3 MSB of fsvq index.
   */
           vgetbits(codewd74,par->gain_index[1],4,4);
           vgetbits(&codewd74[4],par->fsvq_index[0],4,3);
           berr_pos=sbc_dec(codewd74,7,4,&pmat74[0][0],syntab74);
           par->gain_index[1]=vsetbits(par->gain_index[1],4,4,codewd74);
   /*
   ** Decode LSB of second gain index, first gain index using (7,4) Hamming code;
   ** parity bits in 2 LSB of fsvq index, jitter index bit.  Set
   ** jitter index bits to one.
   */
           vgetbits(codewd74,par->gain_index[1],0,1);
           vgetbits(&codewd74[1],par->gain_index[0],2,3);
           vgetbits(&codewd74[4],par->fsvq_index[0],1,2);
           vgetbits(&codewd74[6],par->jit_index,0,1);
           berr_pos=sbc_dec(codewd74,7,4,&pmat74[0][0],syntab74);
           par->gain_index[1]=vsetbits(par->gain_index[1],0,1,codewd74);
           par->gain_index[0]=vsetbits(par->gain_index[0],2,3,&codewd74[1]);
           par->jit_index = 1;
       }
       } /* if (par->uv_flag && !erase) */
   
       return(erase);
   
   }
   
   float *vq_msd2(float *cb, float *u, float *u_est, float *a, int *indices, int *levels, int stages, int p, int conversion)
   {
       float *u_hat,*cb_currentstage;
       int i;
   
       /* allocate memory (if required) */
       if (u==(float*)NULL)
       {
           MEM_ALLOC(MALLOC,u_hat,p,float);
       }
       else
           u_hat = u;
   
       /* add estimate on (if non-null), or clear vector */
       if (u_est)
       {
           (void)v_equ(u_hat,u_est,p);
       }
       else
       {
           (void)v_zap(u_hat,p);
       }
   
       /* add the contribution of each stage */
       cb_currentstage = cb;
       for(i=0; i < stages; i++)
       {
           (void)v_add(u_hat,&cb_currentstage[indices[i]*p],p);
           cb_currentstage += levels[i]*p;
       }
   
       return(u);
   }
   
   /* V_ADD- vector addition */
   float *v_add(float *v1,float *v2,int n)
   {
       int i;
   
       for(i=0; i < n; i++)
           v1[i] += v2[i];
       return(v1);
   }
   
   /* v_zap - clear vector */
   
   float *v_zap(float *v,int n)
   {
       int i;
   
       for(i=0; i < n; i++)
           v[i] = 0.0;
       return(v);
   } /* V_ZAP */
   
   /* V_EQU- vector equate */
   float *v_equ(float *v1,float *v2,int n)
   {
       int i;
   
       for(i=0; i < n; i++)
           v1[i] = v2[i];
       return(v1);
   }
   int *vgetbits(int *y, int x, int p, int n)
   {
       int lsb=0x1; /* least significant bit mask */
       int *retval=y;
   
       if (n < 0 || p < n-1)
       return(NULL);
   
       for (y+=n-1,x>>=p-n+1; y>=retval; y--,x>>=1)
       *y = x & lsb;
   
       return(retval);
   }
   
   int sbc_dec(int x[], int n, int k, int *pmat, int syntab[])
   {
       int bep=syntab[sbc_syn(x,n,k,pmat)];
       if (bep > -1)
       x[bep] ^= 0x1;
       return(bep);
   }
   
   int vsetbits(int x, int p, int n, int *y)
   {
       register int i,j;
   
       if (n < 0 || p < n-1)
       return(x);
   
       for (i=0,j=p; i<n; i++,j--)
       {
       x &= ~(0x1 << j);  /* mask out bit position j */
       x |= *(y++) << j;  /* set bit position j to array value */
       }
       return(x);
   }
   
   int sbc_syn(int x[], int n, int k, int *pmat)
   {
       int retval=0;
       register int i,j;
       for (i=k,j=n-k-1; i<n; i++,j--,pmat+=k)
       retval += (x[i] ^ binprod_int(x,pmat,k)) << j;
       return(retval);
   }
   
   int binprod_int(int *x, int *y, int n)
   {
       int val=(int) 0;
       register int i;
   
       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       val ^= *x++ & *y++;
   
       return(val);
   }
   
   
   
   //channel hader program 
   
   
   #ifndef READ_CHN_H_INCLUDED
   #define READ_CHN_H_INCLUDED
   
   #define LPC_ORD 10          /* LPC order */
   #define NUM_GAINFR 2        /* number of gains per frame */
   #define NUM_BANDS 5         /* number of frequency bands */
   #define NUM_HARM 10         /* number of Fourier magnitudes */
   #define MAX    100        /* number of maximum packets */
   #define CHSIZE 9
   #define NUM_CH_BITS 54
   #define FRAME 180           /* speech frame size */
   #define GN_QLEV 32           /* number of second gain quantization levels */
   #define PIT_BITS 7           /* number of bits for pitch coding */
   #define PIT_QLEV 99          /* number of pitch levels */
   #define PIT_QLO 1.30103      /* minimum log pitch for quantization */
   #define PIT_QUP 2.20412      /* maximum log pitch for quantization */
   #define CHWORDSIZE 6
   #define ERASE_MASK 0x4000    /* erasure flag mask for channel word */
   #define FS_BITS 8            /* number of bits for Fourier magnitudes */
   #define FS_LEVELS (1<<FS_BITS) /* number of levels for Fourier magnitudes */
   #define GN_QLO 10.0          /* minimum gain in dB */
   #define GN_QUP 77.0          /* maximum gain in dB */
   #define GN_QLEV 32           /* number of second gain quantization levels */
   #define MAX_JITTER 0.25     /* maximum jitter percentage (as a fraction) */
   #define UV_PITCH 50         /* unvoiced pitch value */
   #define BEP_UNCORR -2 /* "Uncorrectable" bit error position */
   #define BEP_CORR -1   /* "Correct" bit error position */
   #define UV_PIND 0    /* Unvoiced pitch index */
   #define INVAL_PIND 1 /* Invalid pitch index  */
   #if (ORIGINAL_BIT_ORDER)
   #define MAX_JITTER 0.25     /* maximum jitter percentage (as a fraction) */
   
   /* Original linear order */
   static int bit_order[NUM_CH_BITS] = {
   0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
   6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11,
   12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
   18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
   24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
   30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
   36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
   42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
   48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53};
   #else
   /* Order based on priority of bits */
   static int bit_order[NUM_CH_BITS] = {
   0,  17, 9,  28, 34, 3,
   4,  39, 1,  2,  13, 38,
   14, 10, 11, 40, 15, 21,
   27, 45, 12, 26, 25, 33,
   20, 24, 23, 32, 44, 46,
   22, 31, 53, 52, 51, 7,
   6,  19, 18, 29, 37, 30,
   36, 35, 43, 42, 16, 41,
   50, 49, 48, 47, 8,  5
   };
   #endif
   
   struct melp_param {         /* MELP parameters */
       float pitch;
       float lsf[LPC_ORD+1];
       float gain[NUM_GAINFR];
       float jitter;
       float bpvc[NUM_BANDS];
       int pitch_index;
       int lsf_index[LPC_ORD];
       int jit_index;
       int bpvc_index;
       int gain_index[NUM_GAINFR];
       unsigned int *chptr;
       int chbit;
       int uv_flag;
       float fs_mag[NUM_HARM];
       int *fsvq_index;
       int *msvq_index;
       int msvq_stages;
       int *msvq_bits;
       int *msvq_levels;
   };
   
       unsigned int chbuf[CHSIZE];
       int eras, i;
   
       int length, eof_reached;
       static struct melp_param melp_par;
       static struct melp_param prev_par;
       float speech_out[FRAME];
       static int codewd74[7];
       static int codewd84[8];
   
       extern float msvq_cb[];
       extern float fsvq_cb[];
   
       int pmat74[3][4];
       int pmat84[4][4];
       int syntab74[8];
       int syntab84[16];
   
   int pitch_dec[1<<PIT_BITS];
   
   int melp_chn_read(struct melp_param *par, struct melp_param *prev_par);
   //int unpack_code(unsigned int **p_ch_beg,int *p_ch_bit,int *p_code,int numbits,int wsize, unsigned int erasemaks);
   int unpack_code( unsigned int (**p_ch_beg), int *p_ch_bit, int *p_code, int numbits, int wsize,  unsigned int erasemaks);
   void fill(float output[], float fillval, int npts);
   void q_gain_dec(float *gain,int *gain_index,float qlow,float qup,float qlev);
   void quant_u_dec(int index, float *p_data,float qmin, float qmax, int nlev);
   void q_bpvc_dec(float *bpvc,int *bpvc_index,int uv_flag,int num_bands);
   int fec_decode(struct melp_param *par, int erase);
   float *vq_msd2(float *cb, float *u, float *u_est, float *a, int *indices,int *levels, int stages, int p, int conversion);
   float *v_add(float *v1,float *v2,int n);
   float *v_zap(float *v,int n);
   float *v_equ(float *v1,float *v2,int n);
   int *vgetbits(int *y, int x, int p, int n);
   int sbc_dec(int x[], int n, int k, int *pmat, int syntab[]);
   int vsetbits(int x, int p, int n, int *y);
   int sbc_syn(int x[], int n, int k, int *pmat);
   int binprod_int(int *x, int *y, int n);
   
   #endif // READ_CHN_H_INCLUDED
   
   
   // spbstd.h
   
   /*
   
   2.4 kbps MELP Proposed Federal Standard speech coder
   
   version 1.2
   
   Copyright (c) 1996, Texas Instruments, Inc.
   
   Texas Instruments has intellectual property rights on the MELP
   algorithm.  The Texas Instruments contact for licensing issues for
   commercial and non-government use is William Gordon, Director,
   Government Contracts, Texas Instruments Incorporated, Semiconductor
   Group (phone 972 480 7442).
   
   
   */
   
   /*
      spbstd.h   SPB standard header file.
   
      Copyright (c) 1995 by Texas Instruments, Inc.  All rights reserved.
   */
   
   #ifndef _spbstd_h
   #define _spbstd_h
   
   /*
   ** Needed include files.
   */
   
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <math.h>
   
   /* OSTYPE-dependent definitions/macros. */
   
   #ifdef SunOS4
   
   /* some standard C function definitions missing from SunOS4 */
   extern int fclose(FILE *stream);
   extern int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
   extern size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nobj, FILE *stream);
   extern int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int origin);
   extern size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nobj, FILE *stream);
   extern int printf(const char *format, ...);
   extern long random(void);
   extern int sscanf (char *s, const char *format, ...);
   extern void rewind(FILE *stream);
   
   #else
   
   #endif
   
   /*
   ** Constant definitions.
   */
   #ifndef FALSE
   #define FALSE           0
   #endif
   #ifndef M_PI
   #define     M_PI    3.14159265358979323846
   #endif
   #ifndef PI
   #define PI              M_PI
   #endif
   #ifndef TRUE
   #define TRUE            1
   #endif
   #ifndef TWOPI
   #define TWOPI 6.28318530717958647692
   #endif
   
   /*
   ** Macros.
   */
   
   #ifndef FREE
   #define FREE(v)         if(v)(void)free((void*)(v))
   #endif
   #ifndef program_abort
   #define program_abort(s1,s2,i1,i2) (void)fprintf(stderr,"%s: %s (instance %d, line %d)",s1,s2,i1,i2),exit(1)
   #endif
   #ifndef SQR
   #define SQR(x)          ((x)*(x))
   #endif
   
   /* Generic memory allocation/deallocation macros. */
   
   #define MEM_ALLOC(alloc_routine, v, n, type) \
           if(((v) = (type*) alloc_routine((n) * (int)sizeof(type)))!=NULL)\
                   ; else program_abort(__FILE__,"MEM_ALLOC",0,__LINE__)
   #define MEM_2ALLOC(alloc_routine,v,n,k,type) \
                   if((v=(type**)alloc_routine((int)sizeof(type*)*(n)))!=NULL\
              &&(v[0]=(type*)alloc_routine((int)sizeof(type)*(n)*(k)))!=NULL)\
                        {int u__i; for(u__i=1; u__i < n; u__i++)\
                                   v[u__i] = &v[u__i-1][k];\
                        }\
                   else\
                           program_abort(__FILE__,"MEM_2ALLOC",0,__LINE__)
   
   #define MEM_FREE(free_routine, v) \
       free_routine(v)
   #define MEM_2FREE(free_routine, v) \
       if (1) { free_routine((v)[0]); free_routine(v); } else exit(1)
   
   /* lint-dependent macros. */
   
   #ifdef lint
   #define MALLOC(n)   (malloc((unsigned)(n)),NULL)
   #define VA_ARG(v,type) (v,(type)NULL)
   #else
   #define MALLOC(n)   malloc((unsigned)(n))
   #define VA_ARG(v,type) va_arg(v,type)
   #endif
   
   #endif /* #ifndef _spbstd_h */
```

Comment: So please what is line 104 in file `read_chn.h`?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the line which causes this warning. That line is probably making a call to upack_code and its line number is most likely printed as part of the output from the compiler. It would also be interesting to see the declarations of any variables given as parameters given to upack_code.

Comment: read_chn.h and read_chn.c is a program which read a vector of structure in a specific manner, the line is: erase |= unpack_code(&par->chptr,&par->chbit,&bit_buffer[bit_order[i]],1,CHWORDSIZE,ERASE_MASK);

Comment: the initialization of parameters is : 
   #define num_ch_bits  54
   #define chwordsize  6
   #define erase_mask   0x4000 
    int erase = 0;
    int i, bit_cntr;
    unsigned int *bit_ptr;
    static unsigned int bit_buffer[NUM_CH_BITS];
    /* Read channel output buffer into bit buffer */
    bit_ptr = bit_buffer;

Comment: after compiling step by step, an error occur: program received signal sigsegv segmentation fault in the line  ret_code = *ch_word & ERASE_MASK;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon, but it is more urgent that you read about how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  Line 104 is seldom appropriate in an MCVE. When you do need to provide clarification, please add it to the question itself, rather than in comments.  You can edit your own question, and you can format code etc in a question in a way you cannot in comments. Please move the contents of your comments into the question, then delete the (now obsolete) comments.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after searching i found that **p_ch_beg parameter may cause the problem (if i'm right)

Your diagnosis is incorrect. `p_ch_beg` is argument 1. Your warning message tells you the problem is argument 3:

> warning: pointer targets in passing **argument 3** of 'unpack_code' differ in signedness

Argument 3 is `int *p_code`. What the warning is telling you is that this argument is expected to be a pointer to an **`int`**, but you're giving a pointer to an *`unsigned int`* instead.

You have two options for fixing this. Choose one:

- Change the type of `bit_buffer` from an array of `unsigned int` to an array of `int`.
- Change `int *p_code` to `unsigned int *p_code`.

P.S. In your example, argument 2 is also incorrect. `&par> chbit` will evaluate to an `int` (if you're lucky; it's technically undefined behaviour), but the argument type is `int *` (pointer to `int`). Did you mean `&par->chbit`?

Comment: yes, i mean &par->chbit

Comment: @HamzaKHEDDAR ... and you meant for the code you show us to compile, too. Unfortunately it doesn't, so technically speaking we can't reproduce the circumstances you're seeing. Luckily, I could deduce the cause of the problem without the carelessly-placed loop at the end rendering your code invalid. I hope this answer has helped. P.P.S `return` isn't a function. Not even by a long shot.

Comment: Thank you for valuable advice @Seb , i've applied your 1 suggestion i've got the two warnings:
read_chn.c:172:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
read_chn.c:179:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]

which they talks about the following line:  `bit_ptr = bit_buffer; '  in both lines 173 and 179

Comment: the function return  255 value

Comment: i have add more details for my program, please have a look

ps: the block programe i'm talking about has been taken from a huge project that i have tested and it's works well, i have bring those functions for my need and integrate it in my main , and it cause errors

Comment: You don't actually need any of this code to demonstrate your problem. All you need is a blank function with the same signature as `update_code`, and a `main` entry point that calls it. For example: `int unpack_code(unsigned int **p_ch_beg , int *p_ch_bit, int *p_code, int numbits, int wsize, unsigned int erasemaks) { return 0; }` followed by `int main(void) { unsigned int bit_buffer[42]; unpack_code(NULL, NULL, &bit_buffer, 0, 0, 0); }`... Please work on your ability to produce [**Minimal**, **Complete** and Verifiable Examples (MCVEs)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @HamzaKHEDDAR Note my emphasis on **Minimal** and **Complete**. Use my program to note that the warning is replicated. Then change `bit_buffer` to `int bit_buffer[42];` and watch it vanish. This is my proof to you that my answer solves your problem.

Comment: thank you so much,exactly, the warning vanish after checking with a MCVE exemple you suggest, but the program still bloc (return 255) after i've add to unpack_code function the following: 
 int ch_bit;
unsigned int *ch_word;
ch_bit = *p_ch_bit;  
please check

Comment: after debugging step by step:  *p_ch_bit=Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Comment: Your question is about the warnings. What relevance does any of this new information have to the warnings?

Comment: you mean, i must open new topic for this, @Seb?